# Mailgun will no longer support TLS 1.0/1.1, does this affect CiviCRM Smtp

Tags: civimail, smtp

I am using Mailgun for sending the email newsletters. I do not use the Mailgun API for sending, just the standard SMPT configuration. Now MailGun sends me the following, bit disturbing email:

```
 Mailgun will no longer support TLS 1.0/1.1
```

I assume CiviCRM uses a more recent version, but where can I find this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For SMTP Civi by default uses pear::mail, which uses Net_SMTP. The current version of Net_SMTP that civi has supports TLS 1.2. See https://github.com/pear/Net_SMTP/blob/18b5dbaa049bee5f6d02c9a4318db02472e2c922/Net/SMTP.php#L613

It also depends on the version of the openssl extension you have installed in your php. If you run `php -i | grep -i openssl` or look at the output of phpinfo, you most likely have newer than openssl 1.0.1 so should be good.

Comment: Thanks, our installation is OK. I looked for the SSL version on https://<server>/admin/reports/status/php . (We use drupal 7).